# Text aligned left and right in a Button

Tags: android, button, text, justify

I have a button which shall look like

```
[1         44.33]
```

so that the text is aligned to left and right at the same time.

Is it possible to achieve it with a single element, w/o introducing nested `TextView`s?

Comment: Its a single button or u want switch? Better if u provide screenshot of what u want.

Comment: no switch. plain <Button/>

Comment: I don't believe there is any standard way to do it with alignment.  You could however add built-in tabs in between your numerical values so that you always have that space between them in a single button.

Comment: `Button` inherits from `TextView` and I don't think you can achieve a "good enough" result with one text view.

Comment: So [this](http://sketchtoy.com/64565644) is what u want, right?

Comment: yepp, this is what I want

Comment: How about toggle button?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `ellipsize` to `middle` and set `singleLine` to `true` for Button.

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="so that the text is aligned to left and right at the same time.Is it possible to achieve it with a single element, w/o introducing nested TextViews?"
            android:textColor="#888686"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
```

Comment: sorry, no ellipsize dots should be shown in the middle. Updated my original question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check the ellipsize element in Button Tag.